# Highest tier of armor?

Tags: terraria-console

I've been looking around the world and there has always been at least like 10 tiers higher and I want to know the highest tier in terraria. I was really wanting to know if someone could help me.

Comment: Armor varies a lot in this game.  You're better off reading [the Wiki page on armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Armor) and choosing one you think is best.

Comment: To close voters: This question may not be great, but it is not off-topic. There is a very clear answer available. It is not opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly based on preference , as there's 3 main classes (Melee, Summoner, and Ranged.)

You can go for high defense armor, Or you can go for buff armor (Armor that gives boosts such as more minions)

If you could specify your playstyle, we can help you more. as it's very different per class, or even per player.

Comment: What about mage/magic classes? E.g nebula armor sets

Comment: Mage / Magic classes can be considered range aswell. As you basically shoot fire and stuff outta nowhere! But yeah, you're right. Mage and Magic classes have their specific armor too. That is what I meant with Playstyle, as for melee you can use different weapons, such as a mace, or a sword.

Comment: Just FYI, Terraria does make a distinction between ranged and magic damage. Though both classes can do damage from a distance, mages are not considered "ranged" for purposes of damage calculation, so it's not entirely accurate to say that "Magic classes can be considered range as well".

Comment: Hm, Good point. Thanks for the information, as I didnt know this before! :)

Answer (score 1):

For console, the highest tier of armor is the armor you can craft/win from Ocram. Using the Souls of Blight dropped by Ocram, you can craft the [Spectral](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Spectral_armor), [Titan](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titan_armor), and [Dragon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dragon_armor) armor sets. Spectral armor is meant for mage-style characters, Titan is for ranged, and Dragon is for melee.

For PC, the strongest tier you can craft are the celestial armors: [Solar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_armor) is for melee, [Vortex](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vortex_armor) is for ranged, [Nebula](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nebula_armor) is for magic, and [Stardust](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stardust_armor) is for summoners. You can only craft these using Luminite, which is crafted from the ore dropped by the Moon Lord.